# 406 org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException while consuming a REST service

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, spring-boot

I am getting 406 response with "HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException" while invoking REST service from angularJS.

#### Angular rest call

```
$http.get('/MongoMicroServices-0.1.0/user/getByMailId/' + $scope.username).then(function(response){
            //alert(response.data);
        },
        function(response){
            console.log("Error!");
        });
```

#### Rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getByMailId/{emailId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUserByMailId(@PathVariable String emailId)
{
    return userService.findUserByEmailId(emailId);
}
}
```

#### Response

```
{"timestamp":1472558929345,"status":406,"error":"Not Acceptable","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException","message":"Could not find acceptable representation","path":"/MongoMicroServices-0.1.0/user/getByMailId/admin@gmail.com"}
```

I am using spring boot. Below are the dependencies of spring boot.

#### pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `User` object, presumably in `json` formatting.

First of all, you should say that by adding the `produces='application/json'` to your `@RequestMapping`. That will prevent many troubles in the future.

Secondly, you should have an object serializer in the classpath, such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Using-Jackson2-with-Maven) (and your `User` class should implement `Serializable`, but that's just for your peace of mind in most cases).

Comment: Yes. There is something wrong while converting User java object to JSON format. But yeah, Jars _jackson-mapper-asl_ and _jackson-core-asl_ are already there available in classpath.

Comment: Not sure which versions of Spring you are using, but the jackson mapper asl is a rather old version of jackson. The current libs are https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Comment: Spring version is 4.2.6. Spring Boot version is 1.3.5. I am using spring boot(added pom.xml in above question section). What I believe is, it is not required to add jackson related jars additionally as spring-boot-starter-data-rest itself downloads Jackson related jars. I can see the Jackson related jars in dependency hierarchy. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are not wrong -- the Jackson dependencies should be brought in by the starter Spring boot package: just not those dependencies. With Spring Boot 1.3.5, I get jackson-core-2.6.6, jackson-annotation-2.6.6 and jackson-databind-2.6.6, and the request works as expected.

Comment: Also, a bit off topic -- spring-data-rest has a slightly different purpose, which is to let you expose domain objects without writing controllers, i.e. directly from the repository. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#install-chapter

Comment: Found the cause !!. I was passing 'admin@gmail.com' as path variable. But the rest service is not accepting the domain name, i.e '.com'. So now by just passing 'admin@gmail' it is working. But I am not sure why it is not working for 'admin@gmail.com' value passed in the url.

Comment: I replicated your setup and it works with path variable and .com ending. Can you try upgrading to Spring Boot 1.4 and rebuilding your app? If that fails, try replacing your -data-rest with the web starter dependency from Spring Boot, if you're not using the -data-rest for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this exception is misleading and happens because of the object that you are trying to send in response (in this case User object). This class should have proper getter methods because Jackson relies on the existence of getter methods.